# passing a float from awk to bash

Tags: bash, awk

I need to add a non-integer counter value of a loop to the counter of another loop. like what follows:

I have a two loops like:

```
numi=$(awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<=.4;i+=0.2)print i}')
numj=$(awk 'BEGIN{for(j=.1;j<=1;i+=0.3)print j}')
for i in $numi
do
for j in $numj   
do
```

***then here I want to change j eg. to j+i and do blah blah but
the problem is that bash does not like float and I can't find a way
to pass the float value. As I'm running another software through this
loop and use the value to feed that software I have to do it in bash
or somehow pass the values to bash.

Comment: Do the whole thing in a single `awk` script... `awk 'BEGIN{for(i...)for(j...){s=i+1; t=i*j/2; system("program" " " s " " t)}}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> j+i and do blah blah but the problem is that bash does not like float

if this is your concern, see if below example helps:

```
$ bc<<<'3.5+1'
4.5
```

Comment: once I say $ k=$((i+j)) it gives an error: invalid arithmatic operator (error token is ".1")

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(seq 0 .2 .4)
do
  for j in $(seq .1 .3 1)
  do
    j_and_i=$(($i+$j))
    echo $j_and_i
  done
done
```

The $() construction executes the command within parentheses and substitutes the results into your line.  The `seq` command prints a sequence of numbers.  In these cases it's given a FIRST, INCREMENT, and LAST values to use.  `seq .1 .3 1` results in "0.1 0.4 0.7 1.0".

The $(()) construction does math.  `$((1+1))` is 2, for example.

Comment: You should explain how this code solves the problem.

Comment: still the same error  syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".4+0")